# Issues with KeyboardEvent in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have a function:

```js
    const handleHotKeys = (event: KeyboardEvent): void => {
      // other code here
    };
```

and markup like this:

```js
return (
      <label
        htmlFor={id}
        className='flex flex-col items-start gap-1 w-full md:w-2/4 text-lg relative'
      >
            <textarea
              placeholder={placeholder}
              id={id}
              className='customScroll w-full'
              value={value}
              onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
              onKeyDown={getHotkeyHandler([
                ['mod+B', handleHotKeys],
                ['mod+I', handleHotKeys],
                ['mod+alt+T', handleHotKeys],
                ['mod+alt+C', handleHotKeys],
                ['shift+(', handleHotKeys],
                ['[', handleHotKeys],
                ['shift+{', handleHotKeys]
              ])}
            />
      </label>
    );
```

**The following error appears**: Type '`(event: KeyboardEvent) => void`' is not assignable to type '`(event: KeyboardEvent | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>) => void`'. Types of parameters '`event`' and '`event`' are incompatible. Type '`KeyboardEvent | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>`' is not assignable to type '`KeyboardEvent<Element>`'. Type '`KeyboardEvent`' is missing the following properties from type '`KeyboardEvent<Element>`': locale, nativeEvent, isDefaultPrevented, isPropagationStopped, persist ts(2322).

Typescript 5.2.2
`getHotkeyHandler` is a function from mantine hooks library (checked the docs, didn't help)
**KeyboardEvent from React is imported**

I tried a lot of things (googled it, asked chatgpt), but nothing works for me, error still appears.
I tried `React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>` and `KeyboardEvent | React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>` this don't work too.

I will be very grateful if you can tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getHotkeyHandler` function expect a more general `KeyboardEvent` type.

For me helped this type: `React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement> | KeyboardEvent`

`React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLElement>` is KeyboardEvent from React, exactly `<HTMLElement>`, even i have textarea if i type it like `React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>` it doesn't work.

And `KeyboardEvent` the default type from Typescript.

Only this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import `KeyboardEvent` from react, there is a native type with the same name.

Comment: I imported it, I'm sorry I didn't specify this in the question

Comment: Wait .. what is the output type of `getHotkeyHandler()`?

Comment: It returns nothing (void) The function itself detects when the right keys are pressed and toggles function that you specified